# ¿Cómo restringir el tipo de archivo a subir en un input file html?

Tags: html5

Quiero subir imágenes a mi servidor, la subida funciona normal, sin embargo quiero restringir el tipo de archivo a subir, de tal manera que solo me deje seleccionar imágenes tipo **jpeg** al momento de que se abre la ventana de selección de archivos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se puede usar el atributo **accept** del tag input. Para aceptar archivos de tipo jpeg, se puede usar el siguiente código.

```html
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

Para permitir cualquier tipo de imágenes se puede usar el siguiente código

```html
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />
```

**accept**

Este atributo indica los tipos de archivo que el servidor acepta, de otra manera será ignorado. El valor debe ser una lista de tipos de contenido únicos, separados por coma:

- Una extensión de archivo, comenzando por el caracter STOP (U+002E).
  (Ejemplos: ".jpg,.png,.doc")
- Un tipo MIME válido sin extensiones
- audio/*, que representa archivos de audio HTML5
- video/*, que representa archivos de vídeo HTML5
- image/*, que representa archivos de imagen HTML5

Las versiones de los navegadores que soportan este atributo son las siguientes:

[image: navegadores]

Comment: Aclara entonces que el atributo accept recibe un mime-type, +1

Comment: buena! no sabia que existia ese atributo xd

Comment: Muchas gracias por valiosa colaboración

Comment: Es bueno tener váidaciones como estas, pero no hay que confiarse, ya que con dos clicks se puede burlar. Lo mejor seria tener válidaciones Back-End por igual.